# Finding p-value given a T test statistic

Tags: statistics

I was wondering what the formula is for computing the p-value given the degrees of freedom and the $t$ test statistic value for a one-sample and two-sample T-test. I could not seem to find the formula online other than just calculators or T-tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cumulative distribution function of t-Student distribution is based on a gamma function and its integral. It is rather difficult to apply the formula because the integrals are not elementary. So, only approximation has a practical meaning.